# Como executar um módulo em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, módulo-python

tenho uma dúvida. Há alguns dias estou criando uma aplicação com interface GUI para mostrar programações de cinema. Ela foi construída em módulos, por exemplo, um módulo cuida das imagens, procura na web e download. Outro módulo cuida das outras informações como procurar sinopses, orçamentos dos filmes, atores. Outro, cuida de pegar horários e informações do cinema e outro da GUI.

Minha dúvida é, como interligar esses módulos? Pois nem tudo no módulo está dentro de função. O módulo de imagens baixa as capas dos filmes por meio de um for fora de uma função.

Como fazer com que o meu módulo principal execute todo o código do módulo? devo fazer tudo virar função?

Esse projeto esta sendo feito apenas para me ajudar no aprendizado.
Desde já agradeço :)

Comment: A resposta do @nbro é adequada à sua pergunta. Por outro lado, há um comentário a se fazer. Muitos consideram uma má prática colocar instruções executáveis em seus módulos (ou em `__init__.py` de seus packages). O argumento é que é um comportamento inesperado. Quando você importa um módulo você normalmente espera que ele apenas defina alguns objetos (constantes, classes, funções, etc.) Se seus módulos têm muito código assim, um dia pode ser difícil entender algum bug ou mover coisas de um módulo para outro. Pelo menos eu experimentei esse tipo de problema algumas vezes.

Answer (score 1):

Quando tu *importas* um módulo, se tiveres código a nivel do módulo (como o teu `for` loop), esse vai ser executado nesse mesmo momento. Portanto, se quiseres que no momento do *import* algum código seja executado imediatamente, podes fazer com que esse código seja global (como o teu `for` loop), ou então podes encapsula-lo numa função, e chama-la diretamente do teu módulo ou do módulo onde essa é definida.

Por exemplo, supõe que eu tenho o seguinte módulo `A`:

```
# módulo A

# código global
for i in range(10):
    print(i)

# função qualquer
def some_function():
    print("some function")
```

Que tu queres importar no seguinte módulo `B`:

```
# módulo B

import A  # importando módulo A

A.some_function()
```

No exato momento em que importas `A`, o `for` loop vai ser executado imediatamente, porque esse não está encapsulado numa função. Nota bem que o código da função `some_function` é executado porque eu estou chamando-a.

Comment: Essa resposta está correta.